# Importrange based on name of country with single formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm newbie about google sheet..

How to importrange from different sheet based on name of country
this my step:

1. the formula placing in sheet REKAP ALL IKU cell B5-B10---(in col. "country"). I want single formula if possible.
2. sheet SBSK (1/13) as data sources with data from C7 till H12

Here link my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NrhJ863JaExJge4ZeAW0kYpXYI8_kzaNs6Dupdf2Mko/edit?usp=sharing

Anyone help me out.

Comment: While a link to a Google Sheets spreadsheet might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained, b/c as it happened with the link included it points to a spreadsheet that was deleted. Considering this, add the relevant information about your spreadsheet directly into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

[image: tentativo]

1. koyone langkah sing ora ana guna kanggo nyiapake rumus kanggo unsur sing wis ana ing kolom B (saka B5 nganti B10) SBSK (1/13)
2. Mulane sampeyan mung kudu ngimpor kabeh kolom saka B7: H12

---

1. it would seem a useless step to prepare a formula for elements you already have in column B (from B5 to B10) of SBSK (1/13)
2. for this reason you just need to import all the columns from B7: H12

`=query('SBSK (1/13)'!B7:H12;"select * ")`

Yen aku ora ngerti apa sing sampeyan pengin entuk, aja ragu-ragu takon pitakon sing luwih rinci lan luwih spesifik

---

If I don't understand what you wanted to achieve, feel free to ask further and more specific questions